# Dynamic Form builder Database Structure

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have more  I'm trying to create dynamic forms and publish them on the web for their users to fill out.

As for the database I'm using **Postgres**,

How could I structure this in the Database:

I would have these following models:

**Form** - that stores for Form

```
 id (PK)
  name
```

**Form Input** - single input that is added to form

```
id (PK)
form_id (FK to forms.id)
type (can be input, dropdown etc)
```

But how could I add model for saving those values, when user view form and popuplate it ?

How could I connect all of that ?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem or question are. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. For code questions give a [mre]. For DB design give DDL.

Comment: You could use something like a `form_instance` and `input_instance` table. The value of a particular input instance is stored in a column in  `input_instance`. `form_instance` references a form and `input_instance` a form instance. Making sure there are only instances of inputs that belong to the form the the form instance belongs to will be a little tricky. You'll need to write a constraint trigger for that.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck.

Answer (score -2):

Not very experienced with node..
So consider this as a guideline(at least java,cpp and python works similar).

1. After db is created you need to connect to it from your program(app showing the form).
2. You do this with some kind of function/method (might need an external library/modul or what to call it).
3. When you are done writing to the db you close the connection(not sure if you maybe just can shutdown the program in node).

So my suggestion is to search for DB-connection in node somewhere.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. Moreover the question is not clear.